# Spring dynamic wiring

Tags: spring

In the case of wiring in Spring (using the qualifier annotation), why spring does not allow the qualifier to be a dynamic value ? 
For example I want to inject a notifier implemetation object in a person object based on a value found in the person object.

what would be the best solution for such situation?

thanks